# How to use perception_odu as a dependency?

Tags: ros, external-libraries, manifest.xml, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys, I have created a package for 3D registration using a Kinect, I would like to use the normal distribution transform that are available in the perception_odu package. I have downloaded and compiled this package successfully in my fuerte_workspace and added it to the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. However, when I add this line to the manifest.xml: `<depend package="perception_oru"/>`  I get the following error:`Error: package/stack firefly_mv depends on non-existent package perception_oru`.

Any help of how to use this package in my registration package would be much appreciated.

thanks,
Khalid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/77101/how-to-use-perception_odu-as-a-dependency?/) by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2013-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok I realized that perception_oru is a stack, therefor the solution was to add `<depend package="ndt_registration"/>` which is the package I require and is part of the perception_oru stack.

---

Originally posted by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) with karma: 735 on 2013-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0